# How to store a group of data with 2 different search parameters?

Tags: c#, list

I have a class to contain following data relevant to this question (Xpos, Ypos, Timestamp)

The size is a 100x100 area (Xpos and Ypos), and have an update time on each position which is the timestamp, the class then is given a new timestamp for next update.

Now I could go through all of these data points and find any class where the Timestamp is up, and execute the action needed. To me this seems inefficient.

Alternative I could store this in a sorted list, with the Timestamp being the decider, so I only need to check through until I find an entry not ready to be updated, update those and remove/readd them with the new timestamp.

Now my kicked is, the expected next timestamp can be modified via workflow that finds the location via Xpos and Ypos, meaning I would have to loop through all entries again to perform this.

I could address this with the objects being in both a sorted list and a 100x100 array, problem is updating the timestamp via the 100x100 array listing, would not update its position in the sorted list.

Is there a good way to approach this "double sorting" without having to go through the full list from either the timestamp trigger point, or from the array update of timestamp.

Comment: I am considering adding an extra class containing the time, and a link to the object, while the object contains a link to this. Use this object in the sorted list. If the timestamp is updated from the Xpos, Ypos reference, it simply null its own link in this reference class, and creates a new entry in the list. This will give sorted null linked objects that is quickly ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to store your data in a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  The [C5 Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/)'s [`IntervalHeap`](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/blob/master/C5/heaps/IntervalHeap.cs) would be a good option for this.  The `IntervalHeap<T>.Replace` method allows you to replace an item (ie: change it's priority, which would be the `Timestamp`) directly.

Comment: I am not following how this helps me when I update the Timestamp to get the objects location updated in the queue.

Comment: @Taoh You can make the comparer based off the timestamp.  A priority queue will automatically sort the items and keep them queued based off the priority (timestamp) for you.

Comment: I simply do not understand this ... if I update the timestamp of the object in the priority queue that gives it a new timestamp, it simply updates its position without having to inform the queue of the update having taken place?

Comment: @Taoh You need to use the `Replace` method to notify it to update.  That's why I mentioned it in there.  (it's just more efficient than using remove/add)

Comment: so if the "update" function in the Storage object has a reference to the list, I would update the timestamp and then perform a list.Replace(this, timestamp) ...?

Comment: @Taoh Yeah, basically.